# Git: fatal: cannot switch branch while rebasing

Tags: git, terminal, rebase

**Problem**

Hi, I have a problem after `rebase` command on RStudio Terminal panel.

Firstly, I have 2 local branches: "main" and "mywork". When I was in one of them (I am not sure which one it was), I did something like `git rebase` (sorry, I don't remember the command exactly). Then the second day, when I was trying to switch to "mywork" branch from the "main" branch using `git switch main`, it said:

```
fatal: cannot switch branch while rebasing
Consider "git rebase --quit" or "git worktree add".
```

I suppose I am in the middle of a "rebase", but I don't know how can I solve that problem.
Thank you for your help.

**What I have tried 1**

As I said above, I have 2 local branches: "main" and "mywork". When I was in one of them (I am not sure which one it was), I did something like `git rebase` (sorry, I don't remember the command exactly). Then the second day, when I was trying to switch to "mywork" branch from the "main" branch using `git switch main`, it said:

```
fatal: cannot switch branch while rebasing
Consider "git rebase --quit" or "git worktree add".
```

So I ran `git rebase --quit` accordingly, then no message popped out; then I ran `git switch main` again, and the same error showed up again:

```
fatal: cannot switch branch while rebasing
Consider "git rebase --quit" or "git worktree add".
```

So I tried the `git worktree add`, and it said:

```
usage: git worktree add [-f] [--detach] [--checkout] [--lock [--reason <string>]]
                        [-b <new-branch>] <path> [<commit-ish>]

    -f, --force           checkout <branch> even if already checked out in other worktree
    -b <branch>           create a new branch
    -B <branch>           create or reset a branch
    -d, --detach          detach HEAD at named commit
    --checkout            populate the new working tree
    --lock                keep the new working tree locked
    --reason <string>     reason for locking
    -q, --quiet           suppress progress reporting
    --track               set up tracking mode (see git-branch(1))
    --guess-remote        try to match the new branch name with a remote-tracking branch
```

I am confused about this message. So I stopped here.

**What I have tried 2**

I then checked the status by `git status`, and it said:

```
On branch mywork
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/mywork' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

You are currently rebasing.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I ran `git rebase --continue` accordingly, but it said:

```
warning: could not read '.git/rebase-merge/head-name': No such file or directory
```

**What I have tried 3**

Under the "mywork" branch, I tried "git rebase --abort" and it said:

```
warning: could not read '.git/rebase-merge/head-name': No such file or directory
```

**System info**

I am using a mac, and I ran the command line on the Terminal panel of RStudio.

Comment: You could try `git rebase --abort` but it will reset to before the rebase

Comment: @base12masterrace Thank you. But I actually have tried that before, and it said, `warning: could not read '.git/rebase-merge/head-name': No such file or directory`. I added that to the question now.